# xmms2 installation on mac 10.7.5 fails using macports

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports

The error I get when trying the following:

```
$cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_audio_xmms2/xmms2/work/xmms2-0.8DrO_o
$sudo ./waf build
```

is:

```
Build failed
 -> task failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4561778192: c avcodec.c -> avcodec.c.1.o}
```

I get an error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'avcodec_init' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

and four warnings:

```
warning: 'avcodec_alloc_context' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

warning: 'avcodec_open' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

warning: 'avcodec_decode_audio3' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

warning: 'avcodec_decode_audio3' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Comment: not well understood the first 3 lines of your problem ... ?

Answer (score 0):

try install a different variant of `xmms2`. Type `port variants xmms2`

```
xmms2 has the variants:
   cpp: C++ development support
   perl: Perl development support
   ruby: Ruby development support
   universal: Build for multiple architectures
```

try this command to install the variant `cpp` of `xmms2`

```
sudo port install xmms2 +cpp
```